# Number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct objects around $r$ alike circles.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $n$ and $r$ be natural numbers with $n \geq r$. Let $S(n,r)$ denote the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct objects around $r$ indistinguishable circles such that each circle has at least one object. Find the value of $S(6,2)$.

Can anyone help me with this question? I have tried it in several ways but couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $6$ distinct objects can be split between two circles as

$5-1,\;4-2\;\; and\;\; 3-3\,$
in $\,\binom65 =6, \binom64=15\;\; and\;\; \frac{\binom63}2 =10$ ways

Each split can be placed in an unnumbered circle in $(n-1)!$ ways, so

- for $5-1$ split, $\;\;4!0!\times 6 = 144$
- for $4-2$ split, $\;\;3!1!\times 15 = 90$
- for $3-3$ split, $\;\;2!2!\times 10 = 40$

Add up

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You need to find a recurrence relation for $S(n,r)$. Consider 2 cases:

1. Arrange the first $n-1$ objects around $r-1$ circles and place the last object in a new circle.
2. Arrange the first $n-1$ objects around $r$ circles and place the last one in one of those circles.

Add these two together and you should have the recurrence relation you are looking for. Now find the base cases and with a few simple calculations, you should be able to figure the value of $S(6,2)$.